# How to align multiple HTML5 sliders?

Tags: css, html

Is there any way to align HTML5 sliders that are nicely aligned with labels? If they have labels with different sizes then it looks awful.

I've even tried to set label width in CSS and it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<html>
<head><style type='text/css'>
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }
  form label { width: 200px; }
</style></head>
<body>
<form>
  <p><label for="name1">John</label><input id="name1" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name2">Jacob</label><input id="name2" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name3">Jingleheimer</label><input id="name3" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name4">Schmidt</label><input id="name4" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does nicely aligned mean for you?

Comment: Each of the sliders has the same starting x-position and the same width.

Comment: @JasonS a `label` is an inline element by default so setting a width won't working unless you set it to `inline-block` or `block`. Then it will take the width.

Comment: gah, I really hate CSS sometimes :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<label>` displays `inline` by default, which means that your `width` won't be applied. Try `display: inline-block`:

```css
form label {
  display: inline-block; /* this is important */
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><label for="name1">John</label><input id="name1" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name2">Jacob</label><input id="name2" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name3">Jingleheimer</label><input id="name3" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name4">Schmidt</label><input id="name4" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
</form>
```

You could also get crazy and jump on the [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) train... but it's new and some browsers don't support it.

```css
.sliders {
  display: grid;
}

.sliders label {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.sliders input {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliders">
  <label for="name1">John</label><input id="name1" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" />
  <label for="name2">Jacob</label><input id="name2" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" />
  <label for="name3">Jingleheimer</label><input id="name3" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" />
  <label for="name4">Schmidt</label><input id="name4" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to set a fixed width on your label.

```css
label {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><style type='text/css'>
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }
</style></head>
<body>
<form>
  <p><label for="name1">John</label><input id="name1" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name2">Jacob</label><input id="name2" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name3">Jingleheimer</label><input id="name3" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
  <p><label for="name4">Schmidt</label><input id="name4" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="0.01" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```